# Check object if DbNull or Nothing and return Double value or 0

Tags: vb.net, object, bindingsource, dbnull

I have a binding source which has datasource from datatable
The table may have fields where its value is Null

When I code this, I get error : *'Public Function xTo0Double() As Double' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed*

```
txt_inv_tot.Text = xTo0Double(bs_payh.Current("_INV_TOT")).ToString("N2")

Function xTo0Double(obj As Object) As Double
    If IsDbNullNothingEmpty(obj) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return CDbl(obj)
    End If
End Function

Function IsDbNullNothingEmpty(obj As Object) As Boolean            
        If obj Is Nothing
            Return True
        End If
        If IsDBNull(obj)
            Return True
        End If
        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj)
                Return True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        
        Return False
    End Function
```

I Did not understand why it gives error... I let the VS IDE correct the error, and it corrected like this

```
Function xTo0Double(obj As Object) As Object
    If IsDbNullNothingEmpty(obj) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return CDbl(obj)
    End If
End Function
```

But I want to return Double, not Object

All this coding to avoid using If Then End If in each time I want to check for field value before using it. for example this code works

```
If IsDBNull(bs_payh.Current("_INV_TOT"))
    txt_inv_tot.Text = "0.00"
Else
    txt_inv_tot.Text = CDbl(bs_payh.Current("_INV_TOT")).ToString("N2")
End If
```

But I don't want to use this way each time I want to read field value that could be Null

Is there is a way ?

Comment: "has no parameters" means that it used the wrong declaration of the function.  Unclear how that happened, maybe a stale assembly reference.

Comment: @HansPassant : Did you try the code at your end and gives the same error?

Comment: Is the function in the same class as to assignment to the text box?

Comment: @Mary : No, the function in different project I add as reference, when I copy the function to the same form I am using it, the error gone. Interesting.. Why?

Comment: I change my function to 
Function xTo0Double(obj As Object,valueIfNull as Double) As Double
    If IsDbNullNothingEmpty(obj) Then
        Return valueIfNull
    Else
        Return CDbl(obj)
    End If
End Function

and it works.. and this is good for me instead using If Not IsDbNull Then Else each time